# I'm having trouble with the resolution of the just the window size of IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, intellij-14

I am having trouble with the window size of IntelliJ when I'm starting a new project. For instance, when I open IntelliJ and click on import project I don't see the "OK", "Cancel" button at the bottom of the window, plus the window cannot be maximized to full screen and I cannot scroll down.

I tried searching in the setting but I just don't understand what setting to click on. I recently started using IntelliJ and I don't wanna enable some setting that i"m not sure of and get into a new mess.

[image: Here is picture one]

[image: Picture 2]

If you look at the pictures above, you can see the buttons or the options are just hidden because of the window size or the resolution of the window.

Comment: It's a known issue, follow https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-135179

Comment: I looked at the conversation people had there. But none of it was useful, they don't talk about fixing it